# determining if swift object has a superclass

Tags: swift, superclass

I would like a runtime test to determine if the current object has a superclass.  The compiler rejects

```
if super {
  //do something
}
```

Any idea of what will work?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the class has any superclass at all, or if it is a subclass of a particular known superclass?

Answer (score 2):

I am testing this on the online REPL cuz that's all I have at the moment. Please let me know if it doesn't work in a regular environment and I'll take it down...

You have a couple of options. First, you can check if an object has a particular superclass by casting with the optional `as?` operator like this:

```
class MyClass { }
class MySubClass: MyClass { }

let mSub: AnyObject = MySubClass()

if let m = mSub as? MyClass {
    println("I am a subclass of MyClass")
}
```

If you just want to know if the object has any superclass at all and you have no idea what that super class might be, you can find out if there is a superclass using the following hack:

```
let mSub: AnyObject = MySubClass()

let description: String = {
    var temp = String()
    dump(mSub, &temp)
    return temp
}()

if let r = description.rangeOfString("super") {
    println("I am a subclass...")
}
```

That should print `I am a subclass...`

And if you want to get real hack-y, you can parse `description` like this:

```
let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\n ")
let classNames = description.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet).reduce([String]()) {
    if let period = find($1, ".") {
        let range = advance(period, 1)..<$1.endIndex
        let className = $1.substringWithRange(range)
        return $0 + [className]
    }
    return $0
}
```

If you print `classNames` you should get: `[MySubClass, MyClass]`

```
// Edit:  Update for Swift4, and wrapped into function
func classHierarchyTypeNames(for object: AnyObject) -> [String] {

    let description: String = {
        var temp = String()
        dump(object, to: &temp)
        return temp
    }()

    let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\n ")
    let classNames: [String] = description.components(separatedBy: charSet).reduce([String]()) {

        // `description` includes quite a lot of non-class cruft.
        // Check for an identifying prefix for your classes, 
        // as well as the `"."` character.
        if ($1 as NSString).range(of: "<#MyFramework#>.").location != NSNotFound, 
            let period = $1.index(of: ".") {
            let classNameStart = $1.index(period, offsetBy: 1)
            let className = $1.suffix(from: classNameStart)
            return $0 + [String(className)]
        }
        return $0
    }

    return classNames
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [superclass()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/superclass)  method that returns an optional AnyClass, so you basically have to check whether it returns nil or not. (if the class doesn't inherit from NSObject, it wont work tho )